# Linking two users in ldap

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I have a set of users in Active Directory. They are technical users, ie not associated to a real person. I need to associate them with some password different from the one they already have. Indeed this password will give them only limited rights as compared to their full rights.

I understand that an appropriate way to do this is to create new users with similar names (for example, if I have an account *username*, I will create *restricted-username*). This way I can give the restricted rights to *restricted-username* and use this user.

But doing this I will end up with twice many users to manage. Is there a way to link two users ? For instance, if I delete *username*, then *restricted-username* is deleted as well ? Or linking properties of the two users (some properties of *restricted-username* would points to the ones of *username*)?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You might get more answers from [Server fault](https://serverfault.com/)